# Adding html element when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a new Bootstrap row to my HTML code when I scroll the mouse downward. Can you provide me with the JavaScript code?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" >
        <div>
            <img src="img/picture1.jpg" alt="pic1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div>
                <img src="img/temp/picture2.jpg" alt="pic2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not how SO works. It's not a free code service. You might look into something like [WOWjs](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) or one of the others and try something on your own first.

Answer (score 0):

To add a row to the parent div:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" >
        <div>
            <img src="img/picture1.jpg" alt="pic1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div>
                <img src="img/temp/picture2.jpg" alt="pic2">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var numItems = $('.row').length;
  if(numItems <= 2){
     $( "#parent" ).append( "<div class='row'>New Row</div>" );
  }
});
```

**Is there a certain point you want it to appear/scroll from?**

If that is the case you can use this when the last row reaches the top:

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var distance = $('.row:last').offset().top,    $window = $(window);
   if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        var numItems = $('.row').length;
        if(numItems <= 2){
           $( "#parent" ).append( "<div class='row'>New Row</div>" );
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you! but how do i limit the number of new added rows ? i only need 2 new rows

Comment: @KikoPayet I've altered the jQuery snippet to suit the two div limit. How's that for you?

Comment: @KikoPayet Please mark this as the right answer if this is what you were looking for. Cheers